# Getting weird characters from a web page

Tags: java, html, web

I am writing a program in Java that parses some text from a web page. But when I use the code below I get weird/incorrect characters.

code:

```
    URL url = new URL(getSearchUrl(crit));
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
    String line;

    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(line);
    }

    br.close();
```

I get the following output:

> ?}?v?8????...

So what am I doing wrong? I know that the site I want to gather info from uses utf-8.

Edit: I am currently in Crotia. I tried some other program I know worked in Serbia (my home country) but it doesn't work here.

Comment: What is the site you're trying to read from? By any chance is it a HTTPS URL?

Comment: What is output of - `getSearchUrl(crit)` , means what is the URL string ?

Comment: The site is: http://kickass.to/usearch/svinja/ . It is http. That site is also the result of getSearchUrl(crit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's g-zipped. you can see it using `connection.getContentEncoding()`.

If you use a `GZIPInputStream` around the `connection.getInputStream()` it should work better.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(new GZIPInputStream(connection.getInputStream()), "UTF-8"));
```